# how to make php code to email login and password to emails in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have some affiliate script that I buy, however this script doesn't have function to

"Send password and login id to all my affiliate" weekly or maybe once per 2 week.

This is because in my experience he/she do not have many members not coming back because not only forgot password but also forgot username.

I want every month the members get email example

---

To: cubaan04@hotmail.com
From : admin@admin.com

Subject : Reminder : Your login name and password for website

Hi Firstname,

We worry if you forgot your login name and password. We love to see you back and active in our network. Here the detail...

your login name : Cubaan04
your password : Cubaan04

please login to website

Your truely
admin website

---

I found this script but dont know how to modified it

```
    <?php

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "plazacen_t", "plazacentrey");
mysql_select_db("plazacen_rak",$db);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `affiliate_users`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
  sendMail($row[0]);
}
mysql_free_result($result);

function sendMail($to){
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello Shahrul';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

?>
```

it not work

and how to put password and login in massage from the database?

Thanks you for read this, iam just noob for this

hope get help from you guys

updated

From our friend answer, i modified it. Yes it send email now but not work like i want, i put

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "plazacen_rak", "rakan852");
mysql_select_db("plazacen_rak",$db);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT email,password,name FROM `affiliate_users`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
sendMail($row[0],$row[1],$row[2]);
}
mysql_free_result($result);

function sendMail($to,$pwd,$id){
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'your login name:". $id ." password: ". $pwd ."';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

?>
```

what I received is email like this;

---

From : webmaster@example.com

the subject
04/04/2015 9.59 PM

your login name:". $id ." password: ". $pwd ."

---

it is not change the $id to username in database, so do the $pwd

don't know whats wrong, any further help. TQ

Comment: Since you didn't define $to so it will not send and username and password need to be append in $message.

Comment: *"and how to put password and login in massage from the database?"* - You don't put the password in an email. If your users can be sent their password, then you don't have a safe system at all. What you should be doing is a reset password method.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, seem most of the user want reminder to them to their email with login and password included.... they say only them can open they email so it is save for them, seem requested by them

Answer (score 0):

First change your query to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email,password,userid FROM `affiliate_users`");
```

Then change your code like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
sendMail($row[0],$row[1],$row[2]);
}
mysql_free_result($result);

function sendMail($to,$pwd,$id){
$subject = 'the subject';
**$message = "your login name:". $id ." password: ". $pwd ."";**
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

**Note**

I do not know what your field names are in the affiliate_users table so replace this "email,password,userid" with your actual field name.

If you want to execute this script every month then you can use cronjob.

Comment: Iam so glad to see the code, i will try it... thank you very much

Comment: I have try it, it emailed to the dummy account but still have problem, see my updated above about the test. Thanks for your help and hope your another help

Comment: okkkyyyy.... i think it is single quote problem.. i am changing littlie code... i will bold the changes..just try and give me feedback

Comment: or try this
 $message = 'your login name:' . $id .' password: '. $pwd;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your sendMail function, You cannot take variables inside single quotes  modify it as

```
function sendMail($to,$pwd,$id){
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = "your login name: {$id} password: {$pwd}";
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

another alternative could be

```
function sendMail($to,$pwd,$id){
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'your login name:' . $id .' password: '. $pwd;
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 }
```

Both will work like a charm.

Comment: If it did, You should upvote it...so that others can also get help from that.